# Error when using html2ps and imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, html2ps

I am trying to convert an html file to an image by using html2ps and imagemagick. This is the command that is being executed:

```
convert ./test.html ./test.png
```

and this is the error I am recieving:

```
Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at /usr/bin/html2ps line 3409.
*** Error opening /tmp/magick-mEFhFOmU
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --currentpoint--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2       %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1       %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3       %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2       --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--       --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--   --dict:407/2000(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Current file position is 27444
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error: /nocurrentpoint in --currentpoint--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
  %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2       %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2       --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--       --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--   --    dict:407/2000(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Current file position is 27444
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: unable to open image `./test.html':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587.
convert: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/magick-Dm8Uf9H1':  @ error/ps.c/ReadPSImage/806.
convert: missing an image filename `./test.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

I have tried searching but had no luck. I partly understand what is going on here but lost on how to fix it.

edit: I am running this on Ubuntu 32-bit

Comment: ***Which*** Ubuntu, mydear? 'Ubuntu' can, from the newest release listed backward: *Precise Pangolin* (12.04), *Oneiric Ocelot* (11.10), *Natty Narwhal* (10.04), *Maverick Meerkat* (10.10), *Lucid Lynx* (10.04), *Karmic Koala* (9.10), Jaunty, Intrepid, Hardy, Gutsy, Feisty, Edgy, Drapper, Breezy, Hoary and Warty.

Comment: Also, which version of ImageMagick (`convert -version`)? Which version of html2ps (html2ps -v`)? I see, Ghostscript is 9.05...